# 3variables xyz line representation

Tags: vector-spaces

If we have the equation 2x+y+3z=6 for example, what does it look like if we were to graph it, can I graph it online or on my calculator?

And if we have the 3 points at which the graph intersect the x,y and z axis we can create this equation, in dutch its called 'assen vergelijking' (which might correspond with 'axis equation', if anyone knows the english word tell me) :

The graph goes through 6,0,0  and 0,3,0 and 0,0,2 so the equation is:
x/6 + y/3 + z/2 = 1  and multiplying by 6 gives us  x+2y+3z=6 so the normal vector is (1,2,3), which apparently stands perpendicular on the plane. I dont understand why the equation represent a line.

Here is how a plane is drawn in my book, the link:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjTperGnurkAhUHNOwKHWHKAOcQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wjvanderzanden.nl%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2FSheets%2520Klas%25205D%2520Hoofdstuk%25208.pdf&psig=AOvVaw1iEiS5ZE4lmM7AMsNXMDbP&ust=1569441284092237

Comment: Here is the right link :https://www.google.com/search?q=assenvergelijking+van+een+vlak&rlz=1C1CHZL_nlNL732NL732&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVoInFoOrkAhWF66QKHcbyB5QQ_AUIEigB&cshid=1569355430613984&biw=1600&bih=789#imgrc=XAuEkq6DB1FwSM:

Comment: You are correct. An equation like $2x+y+3z=6$ does not represent a line. How could it? You can pick *any* point in the $xy$-plane and find a point on the normal through that point. To get a line you need two equations (ie intersecting planes) or a parametric approach eg $(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)+t(d,e,f)$

Answer (score 1):

Given a vector $\textbf{n}$ and a point $P$, the equation of the plane which passes through $P$ and is normal to $\textbf{n}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\langle\textbf{x}-P,\textbf{n}\rangle = 0
\end{align*}

Now substitute $\textbf{x} = (x,y,z)$, $P = (x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$ and $\textbf{n} = (a,b,c)$ in order to obtain
\begin{align*}
a(x-x_{0}) + b(y-y_{0}) + c(z-z_{0}) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow ax + by + cz + d = 0
\end{align*}

where $d = -(ax_{0} + by_{0} + cz_{0})$. Thus the given equation represents a plane in $\textbf{R}^{3}$.